# Function to return SQL query into a vector<double> in C++

Tags: c++, sql, vector

I have a query in T-SQL which returns 300 records. Each record has 2 columns (date, int)

What is the easiest way in C++ to put all the dates in one vector and all the integers in another one?

I would like to do it in a function.

Comment: What is your SQL client library? Which OS and compiler?

Comment: I use "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1", Windows 7x64, Visual Studio 2008, .Net 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to provide full code without knowing your SQL client library - this affects how you populate the `vector`s, but basically you loop through the rows read from the DB doing `push_back` on your two `vector`s for the values retrieved in each row.

The main question is how are you going to handle the returned parameters?  You have two `vector`s, as you have specified the problem here. You could achieve this by having the caller create the `vector`s and then the function populate them, like this:

```
#include <vector>

// function declaration - return false on error, or throw exception if preferred
bool populate(std::vector<double>& dates, std::vector<int>& values);

// calling code
std::vector<double> myDates;
std::vector<int> myValues;

// if you know the row count is 300 ahead of time, do this
unsigned int rowCount;

// rowCount gets set up, to 300 in this example
myDates.reserve(rowCount);
myValues.reserve(rowCount);

// Populate vectors, checking for error (false = error)
if (populate(myDates, myValues)) {
  // work with the returned data
}
```

For extra credit because of better encapsulation or the row data, I would be inclined to use a vector of POD structures.  The advantage of this is that each date and value then remain tightly coupled - you can extend this into a full-blown class if you have operations you wish to do for each row.  Hide the data behind getters, preferably.

```
struct Row {
  public:
    double date;
    int value;
};

bool populate(std::vector<Row>& rows);
```

Comment: Thanks, what about if the value is not 300? How would you handle that?

Comment: The point is that using `reserve` on the vector before you populate it is more efficient because otherwise you will get realloc-and-copy when the default vector size gets full.  An alternative (better?) approach would be to have your `populate` function use the row count resulting from your query to do the `reserve` call, with the input `vector`s still being assumed to be empty.  You could assert or throw on `(!dates.empty())` in `populate`, for example.